# Historical Exchange Rates

Tags: java, javascript

I want to know if there is an API ( it doesn't matter if it is paid or free) in java / javascript which gives Historical Exchange Rates. I have searched and found some:

- https://www.mashape.com/joss/open-exchange-rates#!documentation
- http://currencies.apps.grandtrunk.net/

Please help me in finding a reliable API which gives Historical Exchange Rates.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question! If your point is to share  information resources you might want to post to http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few useful links:

http://openexchangerates.org/documentation#historical-data

[Free Forex Historical Data](http://www.global-view.com/forex-trading-tools/forex-history/index.html)

Yahoo Finance ([Currency Rates](http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GBPEUR=X,EURCHF=X,EURCAD=X,USDEUR=X,EURJPY=X&f=sl1d1t1ba&e=.csv))

See their [data](http://www.federalreserve.gov/datadownload/Download.aspx?rel=H10&series=a6a0113179fdeb9c6fbcdc18575ec09c&filetype=csv&label=include&layout=seriescolumn&from=01/01/2000&to=08/01/2012),you can retrieve (csv, xls, xml) historical data an then use it as per your requirements.